# how to use gx_mappanel?

Tags: geoext

While developing a user interface using Ext.viewport and GeoExt, gx_mappanel tricked me.I'm using OpenStreetMap as base layer and a vector layer.Both layers works fine when I use Openlayers alone for visualization. But not work when I use gx_mappanel as shown in the code.  console of my Firebug shows the warning message as follows:

window.controllers is deprecated. Do not use it for UA detection. OpenLayers.js:1171
Use of inputEncoding is deprecated. Can this warning be the case?

Please look at the code and help. I tried several times without success, It is for fist time that I'm using GeoExt. I think what I lack is the properties of gx_mappanel.

var options = {

```
        projection: mapprojection,
        units: 'm'

    };
```

var map = new OpenLayers.Map(options);

```
      map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine());


  var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();

  map.addLayer(layer);
  map.setBaseLayer(layer);


  var vStyle = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
  pointRadius:4,
  fillOpacity: 1, fillColor: '#ee9900'

 });
```

var vLayer=new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("vLayer",

```
       {

        projection:mapprojection,

        strategies:[new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],

        protocol:new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({

            url: "myserverscript", 

            format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()

        }),

        styleMap: vStyle

      });

    map.addLayer(vLayer); 



new Ext.Viewport({

layout: "border",

items:[{

        region: 'east',

        id: "form",

        title: 'some title',

        width: 200,

        collapsible: true,


        items: [plantInfo]

    },{
        region: "center",

        id: "mappanel",

        title: "map goes here",

        xtype: "gx_mappanel",

        center: new OpenLayers.LonLat(9.05, 51.20).transform( 

                new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), 

                new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913") ), 

        map: map,
        //layers:[layer,vLayer],
        //extent:extent,
        zoom:10

    },
 ]

});
```

Comment: Which versions of Openlayers,GeoExt and ExtJs do you use?

Comment: I'm using Openlayers 2.1, Geoext 1.1 and Extjs4

Comment: There you are.for Geoext 1.x you need Extjs 3.x

Comment: you mean that Extjs4 cannot be used with Geoext1.x?

Comment: yes. see geoext.org:  "A notice about GeoExt versions
This website is about GeoExt 1.x, based on Ext JS 3. There is also a version of GeoExt that is capable of working on top of the newest Ext JS: GeoExt 2."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use Extjs 3.4 instead of ExtJS4:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.4.0/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.4.0/ext-all.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.4.0/resources/css/ext-all.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.4.0/examples/shared/examples.css" />
```